# HTML/CSS Image and Text Overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have created navigation buttons that is responsive, here's the css:

```css
  .cont{
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;

  }
  .btnstyle{

    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    text-align: left;

  }
  .iconer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 9px;
    top: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="cont">
    <a href="#" class="btnstyle">
     <img class="iconer" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2922/2922518.svg">
      <h3> Button</h3>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btnstyle">
      <img class="iconer" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2922/2922518.svg">
      <h3>Button</h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

But the image icon and text overlaps. How do I prevent this from happening? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have the `position: absolute` on the image. This is what is causing the overlap. You can achieve your desired result by changing it to `position: relative`.

```css
  .cont{
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;

  }
  .btnstyle{

    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    text-align: left;
    float:left;

  }
  .iconer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="cont">
    <a href="#" class="btnstyle">
     <img class="iconer" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2922/2922518.svg">
      <h3> Button</h3>
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="btnstyle">
      <img class="iconer" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2922/2922518.svg">
      <h3>Button</h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

By using position absolute you're telling the browser to ignore the layout features (including width / height) of the image, which means that the text will render where it would as though the image wasn't there. By putting it as relative, you're telling the browser to respect the images dimensions and work the layout around it normally.

You can then position the image using top and left in the same way you have been.

Comment: Yes, this works, but I need the image and text to appear beside each other that is why I put the absolute. Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: See update, you just need to use float: left on both elements

Comment: @Paolo07 If this answered your question please accept it so it won't keep coming up as unanswered in question feeds.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `position` ruling to appear them side by side.

**Method 1:**
Update your `.iconer` style to

```
.iconer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

and then add additional

```
h3 {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

They will come inline.

**Method 2**
You can remove others and use `float: left` to appear them inline.

```
.iconer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
 }
```